# fuelUx scheduler method loads incorrect date in my page

Tags: jquery, scheduler, fuelux

```
$('myScheduler').scheduler('value', {
  startDateTime: '2014-03-31T03:23+02:00',
  timeZone: {
  name: 'Namibia Standard Time',
    offset: '+02:00'
  },
  recurrencePattern: 'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=6;BYDAY=WE;BYSETPOS=3;UNTIL=20140919;'
});
```

*Outputs date as: 03/30/2014 in my date picker in Schedule.

**Why am I getting 30 instead of 31 for day**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do get the correct date, `03/31/2014`, in the datepicker input within the scheduler with the following (I added the pound sign):

```
$('#myScheduler').scheduler('value', {
  startDateTime: '2014-03-31T03:23+02:00',
  timeZone: {
  name: 'Namibia Standard Time',
    offset: '+02:00'
  },
  recurrencePattern: 'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=6;BYDAY=WE;BYSETPOS=3;UNTIL=20140919;'
});
```

However, due to the default datepicker behavior being "do not allow past dates," the day is crossed out on the datepicker calendar. What culture are you using with momentjs? I noticed you are looking for the ISO 8601 date format.

Comment: Hi I am not using any format for culture do I have to use Momentjs? and for scheduler output i mean it displays 03/30/2014 and also for end date 09/18/2014 with above input , i think this can also be timezone issue but I am not sure just started to learn dates so does  timezone have any effect on display and with Start time ..  ??

Comment: Fuel UX scheduler will try to parse your date with Javascript's built-in date parser. I would recommend using [Moment.js with locales](http://momentjs.com/#multiple-locale-support) for internationalization options.

Comment: Thank you for answer :) after adding Moment.js it fix the wrong date issue. Looks like javascript parsing has some problem but Moment.js parsing does it correctly. I have also attached the link for working fiddle as my solution [Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkreety/wt4x0f5d/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the problem though i got a solution to my problem by changing the format ,

```
$('#myScheduler').scheduler('value', {
            startDateTime: '2014/03/31T03:23+02:00',
            timeZone: {
                name: 'Namibia Standard Time',
                offset: '+02:00'
            },
            recurrencePattern: 'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=6;BYDAY=WE;BYSETPOS=3;UNTIL=20140919;'
        });
```

This outputs date correctly for me seems like the problem is with date parse, but i still not  sure is this the correct solution for this problem  and why 2014-03-31T03:23+02:00  displays different date than 2014/03/31T03:23+02:00 ?